# Why can't I update dataframe using loc?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to update the range column in this dataframe:

```
            Range  percentchange
Date                                                                    
2014-01-06  0     -13.113459
2014-01-07  0       6.693942
2014-01-08  0      -0.191734
2014-01-09  0       2.219851
2014-01-10  0       4.959282
```

Using the following code prints an unaltered df, I want to update the range column with a number at each row what am I doing wrong?

```
for i, row in newBTC.iterrows():
    df_column_percentchange = newBTC.loc[i, 'percentchange']
    df_column_range = newBTC.loc[i, "Range"]
    if -100 <= df_column_percentchange <= -11:
        df_column_range = -10
    if -11 <= df_column_percentchange <= -9:
        df_column_range = -9
    if -9 <= df_column_percentchange <= -7:
        df_column_range = -8
    #etc...
```

Comment: Because `df_column_range` is not a "reference" into the dataframe.  It's just an integer.  It has no connection to the dataframe itself.  You can say `newBTC.loc[i,'percentchange'] = -10`.

Comment: updating a value in a particular row and column there are various ways using .at, .loc, .replace. But all return a value that is not a reference to the dataframe. 
So storing it in a variable and then trying to update using a variable is not allow. Use the dataframe API directly instead to update them.
please refer here https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/pandas/update-the-value-of-a-row-dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@TimRoberts and @BeRT2me gave you the correct explanation. However, even if you fix that, you could do much better with [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
# For demo purpose only, adapt to your real case
bins = [-20, -1, 1, 20]
labels = [-10, 0, 10]
df['Range'] = pd.cut(df['percentchange'], bins, labels=labels).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
         Date  Range  percentchange
0  2014-01-06    -10     -13.113459
1  2014-01-07     10       6.693942
2  2014-01-08      0      -0.191734
3  2014-01-09     10       2.219851
4  2014-01-10     10       4.959282
```

Comment: Note that there is an inconsistency in OP's logic to try to match equality in successive boundaries (making the intervals overlapping on the boundaries). Given the order of the comparisons this results in `right=True` (the default). This should however also use `include_lowest=True`.

Comment: I don't think we can set whatever values are in the range, like not tampering case. If the value is not in the range of any bin then the default value would be whatever past value

Answer (score 4):

`iterrows` is a trap. It's basically *never* the best way, and leads to more problems than it's worth.

This still isn't a good way of doing it, but if you can't find a good `pandas` specific way to do something, at least implement looping like this:

```
def set_range(x):
    # changed to show more interesting results,
    # make it how you want.
    if -100 <= x <= -11:
        return -10
    elif -11 <= x <= 0:
        return -9
    elif 0 <= x <= 5:
        return -8
    else:
        return 0

df['Range'] = df.percentchange.apply(set_range)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            Range  percentchange
Date
2014-01-06    -10     -13.113459
2014-01-07      0       6.693942
2014-01-08     -9      -0.191734
2014-01-09     -8       2.219851
2014-01-10     -8       4.959282
```

@Corralien has a wonderful example of a `pandas` specific way to approach your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This 'fix' should work for you. However, there are better solution (see answers `@Corralien` and `@BeRT2me`).

```
newBTC = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Date': ['2014-01-06', '2014-01-07', '2014-01-08', '2014-01-09', '2014-01-10'], 
        'Range': [0]*5, 
        'percentchange': [-13.113459, 6.693942, -0.191734, 2.219851, 4.959282]
    }
)
newBTC['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(newBTC['Date'], errors='coerce')
newBTC.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

for i, row in newBTC.iterrows():
    df_column_percentchange = row.percentchange
    df_column_range = row.Range
    if -100 <= df_column_percentchange <= -11:
        df_column_range = -10
    if -11 <= df_column_percentchange <= -9:
        df_column_range = -9
    if -9 <= df_column_percentchange <= -7:
        df_column_range = -8
    if 4 <= df_column_percentchange <= 7:
        df_column_range = 99 # test value
    newBTC.at[i, 'Range'] = df_column_range

print(newBTC)
```

Result:

```
            Range  percentchange
Date                            
2014-01-06    -10     -13.113459
2014-01-07     99       6.693942
2014-01-08      0      -0.191734
2014-01-09      0       2.219851
2014-01-10     99       4.959282
```